# Mojolicious - acting as an http proxy

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm trying to implement a simple http proxy for certain requests for a simple web service using JSON as the payload.

I see some information on this, but no complete examples in the documentation. I've tried some code from blog posts that I found in google search results, but nothing that I could get working. Here is where I am.

The request is passed to a handler object, with a handle method like so

```
sub handle
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $app = shift;

    my $tx = $app->tx;
    my $req = $app->req->clone;
    $log->info("upstream host is " . $self->{upstream_host});
    $log->info("upstream port is " . $self->{upstream_port});
    $req->url->scheme("http")
            ->host($self->{upstream_host})
            ->port($self->{upstream_port});

    $log->info("req: " . $req->to_string);
    $log->info("req host:port " . $req->url->host . ":" . $req->url->port);

    my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
    my $tx = Mojo::Transaction::HTTP->new(req => $req);

    $log->info("response: " . $tx->res->to_string());

    $app->render(data => $tx->res->body);
}
```

Everything in the logs looks correct, but the response object is a 404 error, and no actual traffic reaches my other service listening on localhost:3334.

2013-07-02 12:28:26.929793500 [Tue Jul  2 12:28:26 2013] [info] req host:port 127.0.0.1:3334
2013-07-02 12:28:26.930225500 [Tue Jul  2 12:28:26 2013] [info] response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

I tried the non-blocking version of this but again, no request was actually sent, so I tried to simplify.

Help appreciated, I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here. I'm just trying to duplicate the request, pass it to another service, and then return its response to the original client.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Can you see/confirm that the handle method is getting the arguments you expect (with `Data::Dumper` or some other method) ?

Comment: The input is good. So far I've only gotten this working by dropping the transaction code and doing a basic $ua->get(). The documentation says that using build_tx() with no callback will do a non-blocking request, but I don't see that. In my case it is not performing the request at all.

Comment: Oh, and I'm no CentOS 6 with

perl-Mojolicious-3.05-6.el6.noarch

and perl 5.10.1.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, strange. This works.

```
sub handle
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $app = shift;

    my $tx = $app->tx;
    my $req = $app->req->clone;
    $log->debug("upstream host is " . $self->{upstream_host});
    $log->debug("upstream port is " . $self->{upstream_port});
    $req->url->scheme("http")
            ->host($self->{upstream_host})
            ->port($self->{upstream_port});

    $log->debug("req: " . $req->to_string);
    $log->debug("req host:port " . $req->url->host . ":" . $req->url->port);

    my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
    my $tx = $ua->start(Mojo::Transaction::HTTP->new(req => $req));

    $app->render(data => $tx->res->body);
}
```

I'm trying to see how that's significantly different from what I was already 
doing...

Now, this is a blocking request. Lets see if I can get it working non-blocking.

Comment: This variation does not work

    my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
    my $tx = $ua->start(Mojo::Transaction::HTTP->new(req => $req) => sub {
        my ($ua, $tx) = @_;
        $app->render(data => $tx->res->body);
    });

It's supposed to be non-blocking, but the request just never happens.

Comment: +1 for answering yourself :-)  There's always a chance it could be a bug.  Have you tried with a newer version Mojolicious?

Comment: Mojolicious is now at 4.16 and a quick search for "transaction" reveals there are/were ~ [15 bugs/issues](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/search?p=1&q=transaction&ref=cmdform&type=Issues) reported and that most of those were fixed. might be worth testing. Anyway I look forward to your own explanation of why the second code sample works  +1 for you :-)